# Angularfire2 AuthGuard Explanation

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am fairly new to Angular and I am trying to understand setting up an AuthGuard for blocking certain routes when a user is logged in or not. I found this code while searching around and it does work. However I do not fully understand what the code is doing. If anyone could just explain what everything is doing here it would be a huge help. Thank you!

```
constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth, private router: Router) {}
   canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth
      .take(1)
      .map((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => !!authState)
      .do(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate(['']);
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Angular 2 router tries to access a route, it evaluates the 'canActivate' method on all the guards added to the route in your configuration.

If one of these guards return false, or return an observable that evaluates to false when you subscribe to it, it prevents the router from accessing this page.

Comment: For further information please read I suggest http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html